# How to determine color shades on the basis of double value?

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I have an ArrayList with double values, these values I write out into table. I would like to color (one color - e.g. green or red) each row on the basis of its double value, higher value will have darker shades and vice versa. Maybe I can change lightness - is it correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that creates a Color based on a double value. Something like this:

```
Color getColor(double val, double min, double max) {
  int red = 100;
  int green = 100;
  int blue = val/(max-min) * 256;

  return new Color (red, green, blue);
}
```

You can change the base color by moving the blue computation into other color. Or make a different equation altogether. The idea remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not "wrong" per say.  It's a bit strange.  Personally, if you're trying to represent colours and you don't want to use the Color class, I'd use an int instead of a double.  An int has 32 bits, 8 bits each for red, green, blue and alpha.  I'm not sure exactly how you'd convert a double to a colour.

Comment: You do not acutally provide an answer to the question, you give some more or less relevant information. I think you misudnerstood the question. I think I know what the user wanted and posted my own answer. I may be wrong, however:)